# Modifying install directory for rpm with sbt native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to build an rpm package with the sbt-native-packager that installs in a custom directory eg /opt/myapp instead of /usr - due to in-house policy requirements.

I have a build.sbt that will build a standard rpm but I'm stumped when it comes to modifying the directory.  My apologies-I'm quite new to scala, sbt and the native pacakger.

I am using mapGenericFilesToLinux and would like to keep its structure - just modifying the first part of the destination directory.

I found this code fragment in a git hub issue https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/4#issuecomment-6731183

```
linuxPackageMappings <+= target map { target =>
  val src = target / "webapp"
  val dest = "/opt/app"
  LinuxPackageMapping(
  for {
    path <- (src ***).get
    if !path.isDirectory
  } yield path -> path.toString.replaceFirst(src.toString, dest)
 )
}
```

I believe I want to do something similar except to

```
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm <++= <SOMETHING HERE> { 
   // for loop that steps through the source and destination and modifies the directory
}
```

thanks in advance for any help

bye
Pam

Comment: sbt 0.12 or 0.13?  If 0.13, just use `++=` and the new `.value` on keys.  Otherwise, I'll respond with a full answer.

Comment: thanks for answering.  It's sbt version 0.12.4 and it's being used as part of the play framework (v2.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

So, in sbt 0.12 you need to make sure you specify all the dependent keys you want to use before declaring the value you want.   SO, let's pretend two things:

1. `linuxPackageMappings` has all your mappings for the packaging.
2. `linuxPackageMappings in Rpm` has nothing added to it directly.

We're going to take the value in `linuxPackageMappings` and alter the directory for `linuxPackageMappings in Rpm`:

```
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm <<= (linuxPackageMappings) map { mappings => 
  // Let's loop through the mappings and alter their on-disc location....
  for(LinuxPackageMapping(filesAndNames, meta, zipped) <- mappings) yield {
     val newFilesAndNames = for {
        (file, installPath) <- filesAndNames
     } yield file -> installPath.replaceFirst("/usr/share/app", "/opt/app")
     LinuxPackageMapping(newFilesAndNames, meta, zipped) 
  }
}
```

What this does is rip out the linux package mappings (which include whether or not to gzip files, and the user/group owners/permissions) and modify the install path of each file.

Hope that helps!  IN sbt-native-packager.NEXT (not released) you can configure the default install location.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  When I tried the code as-is in my build.sbt, I got the following error referring to the final "LinuxPackageMapping" line.
    error: not found: value newFilesAndNames

Comment: I tried moving this line inside the brace above so it was in the same scope as the val and this compiled but caused problem later on where a symbolic link had an "File exists" error - I guess because it that code was being called multiple times.  Should I modify the symbolic links as well or is there something else that should be done to fix the first error?

Comment: I fixed up the code to be correct. The issue was my use of <++= instead of <<=, sorry.  You want to *replace* the previous linux package mappings.  What I had listed before was *adding* to the previous ones.

Comment: I have tried this approach and although the install dir in the rpm is changed to desired location, the rpm no longer packages the init.d script. I have an override for start script in my src/template/start so maybe that somehow breaks this. Now my RPM doesn't install since somehow the target/universal/tmp/bin is missing the systemv-init file. Any idea how to get around this?